# How can I make my code ask for an Input instead of hard coding the values

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# so not sure how I can pull this off, in my code I type in the values I need to convert *Console.WriteLine(ToFeet(5.17));*, how can I prompt for an input like *Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ")* and output the conversion *4FT 2IN*.
This could be the same thing but also not sure how to make it a variable(dynamic) so I can call this function elsewhere...

```
using System;
class Code {

public static string ToFeet(double dec)
{
    return $"{Math.Truncate(dec)} FT {Math.Round(12 * (dec - Math.Truncate(dec)))} IN";
}

static void Main() 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ToFeet(5.17));
}

}
```

Since I'm new to C#, I didn't know what could I try, I researched for a bit and tried Console.ReadLine() couldn't get my logic to work...

Comment: [Console.ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @UnholySheep I initially tried using Console.ReadLine() but was getting confused with how would I call function's (dec) first time and then second time... I'll update the question as well, maybe I'm just getting confused with a simple thing but I need someone's help seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ask input, parse it , then pass to function

```
  Console.WriteLine("Enter input");
  var inString = Console.ReadLine();
  double input;
  if(Double.TryParse(inString, out input)) {
     Console.WriteLine( ToFeet(input));
  }
  else {
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
  }
```